# Flutter get location asynchronously and send it to API

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, geolocation

I have a flutter app running only on Android that I need to get the location of the device periodically, it can be like every 10 minutes, but my problem is that getting the location takes time (sometimes more than 2 minutes) so I need a way to achieve this asynchronously, like getting the app location in the background and send it to API. I don't need the API return, only to send the data in a way that is perceptible to the user.